# Component not showing when swipeable container is swiped using code

Tags: codenameone

I have a swipeable container with a button exposed when you swipe it.
It works when you use your mouse to swipe, but it doesnt seem to work when
you use code to perform the same action.

```
    Form hi = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Container multiButtonCont = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    MultiButton mButton = new MultiButton();
    mButton.setTextLine1("mButton 1");
    Button testB1 = new Button("TestButton1");
    SwipeableContainer swipe = new SwipeableContainer(testB1,mButton);
    multiButtonCont.addComponent(swipe);

    Button openButton = new Button("Open");
    openButton.addActionListener(e->{
        for(int i=0;i<multiButtonCont.getComponentCount();i++){
            ((SwipeableContainer) (multiButtonCont.getComponentAt(i))).openToRight();
        }
    });
    Button closeButton = new Button("Close");
    closeButton.addActionListener(e->{
        for(int i=0;i<multiButtonCont.getComponentCount();i++){
            ((SwipeableContainer) (multiButtonCont.getComponentAt(i))).close();
        }
    });
    hi.addComponent(GridLayout.encloseIn(2, openButton, closeButton));
    hi.addComponent(multiButtonCont);
    hi.show();
```

Any ideas on how to implement opening a swipeable container using code?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem but I noticed `multiButtonCont` doesn't have a layout. Try to set it to `BoxLayout.y()`

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem.  The components that display when the multibutton is swiped, only shows when the user swipes it, and doesnt show when code is used to open the swipeable container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the code, it seems to be a regression in the component. I've fixed it and it should be available for the coming update which is on October 7th 2016